# Invert position element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create a screen with boostrap 3.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="injection" id="injection">Injection</label>

 <label for="period" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Immatriculation</label>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <input type="number" min="0" value="52" class="form-control" id="year" name="period" placeholder="Entrer la période en semaine" data-fv-integer="true" data-fv-integer-message="La valeur doit être numérique">
 </div>
```

I put injection element in first position, but it's displayed in second.
Also, is there a possibility to put medical aligned with the other?

Here a demo
https://jsfiddle.net/nqe3k71k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap grid total should be 12 and right now in the code you provided its 9

so i think just add `col-sm-3` in the `Injection` label like below

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="injection" id="injection">Injection</label>
<label for="period" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Immatriculation</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" min="0" value="52" class="form-control" id="year" name="period" placeholder="Entrer la période en semaine" data-fv-integer="true" data-fv-integer-message="La valeur doit être numérique">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I put injection element in first position, but it's displayed in second

Because the label and text field of "Immatriculation" are floated to the left, since they have "control-label" and "col-sm-6" as their css classes. You should make "Injection" be on it own row or add "control-label" to it class attribute

> Also, is there a possibility to put medical aligned with the other?

You meant align "Medical" and "Diabete" to left of the form? Then I think you should wrap them with row and columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**DOM:**

```
           <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="medicalContactId" name="drugId">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="medicate" id="medicate">Medical
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="diabete" id="diabete">Diabete
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="injection" id="injection">Injection
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="number" min="0" value="52" class="form-control" id="year" name="period" placeholder="Entrer la période en semaine" data-fv-integer="true" data-fv-integer-message="La valeur doit être numérique">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tiroir médicale</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select id="medicalDrawer" name="medicalDrawerId" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button id="lodgerMedicalSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox-inline.no_indent,
.checkbox-inline.no_indent+.checkbox-inline.no_indent {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.checkbox-inline.no_indent:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```